# How to select all input and select element inside single or multiple div by id or class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a 
Jquery to detect a change in any field inside div id="goaldiv" \
but with below script is not working.

```
 $('#fhcform .goalv input','#fhcform .goalv 
     select').on('change',function(eve){
                    alert($(this).val());
            });
```

Below is the html code :

```
     <div id="goaldiv">
      <div id="mygoaldiv" >
          <div id="my0Div" class="goalv">
              <input type="hidden" value="0" name="hddgoal_id[]" class="goalid">
               <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 form-pad-bot" class="form-control  inputText"  >
                  <select name="goal_id[]" class="form-control " aria-required="true">
                      <option value=""> Select Goal</option>
                      <option value="1"   > vacation</option>
                      <option value="2"   > child marriage</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 form-pad-bot"> 
                  <input value="" placeholder="Goal Year" class="goal_date form-control  inputText" type="text" name="goal_date[]" >  

              </div>
           </div>   
      </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will make it work, :

```
 $('#goaldiv .goalv input, #goaldiv .goalv      select').on('change',function(eve){
      alert($(this).val());
 });
```

Your code's selector was wrong,

Comment: yes it is working fine , but i doubt that if my main parent div id is fhcform and hence i have used that and it was not working ....can u tell me why so